# how to send email to multiple addresses in java

Tags: java, gmail

I am using this method to send email to two Gmail ids, but this is giving an error that:

> The method addRecipient(Message.RecipientType, Address) in the type Message is not applicable for the arguments (Message.RecipientType, Address[])

How can I send email to multiple ids?

```
 Address toaddress[] = new InternetAddress[2];
 toaddress[0] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_0);
 toaddress[1] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_1);
 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,toaddress);
```

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the API you are using, but would calling `message.addRecipient` twice (once for each email address) work? I ask this since the name `addRecipient` seems to imply you can call it more than once to "add" a recipient.

Comment: Maybe by looping the `email_send` function over all of the recipients! :)

Answer (score 2):

how about using [addRecipients(Message.RecipientType type,Address[] addresses)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Message.html#addRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType,%20javax.mail.Address[]))

```
 Address toaddress[] = new InternetAddress[2];
 toaddress[0] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_0);
 toaddress[1] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_1);
 message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,toaddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
Address toaddress[] = new InternetAddress[2];
toaddress[0] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_0);
toaddress[1] = new InternetAddress(mail_to_1);
for (int i = 0; i < toaddress.length; i++)
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,toaddress[i]);
```

The `addRecipient` method does not take an array as an argument, so you cannot pass it the whole array at once, but assuming it behaves as its name implies, you should be able to loop over the array and call `addRecipient` for each address in the array.